# How GlobalZOrder works in cocos2d-js?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, z-order, cocos2d-html5

I have nested tree:

```
self.addChild(red);
self.addChild(green);
green.addChild(blue);
```

I get this: ([Screenshot](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AAClyostg3iWnAwbL995CwgAF6-ENhzeGSGHRfFdWqOLEQ/12/118500203/png/32x32/3/1450112400/0/2/Screenshot%202015-12-14%2014.21.19.png/EIDPslsYnesKIAIoAg/RP7_CiFdJossjeCSfH-rCyjmMP4JAqPOvdFvn51UxbU?size_mode=3&size=1024x768))

How can I put blue square behind others, without changing my tree to make it look like this: ([Screenshot](https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAFdWIijAY3UWj50qiLQFDB5-e02lEPPaEQr29cu7Cavw/12/118500203/png/32x32/3/1450112400/0/2/Screenshot%202015-12-14%2014.25.06.png/EIDPslsYn-sKIAIoAg/zdcMBOTXDYm-KRe71TiQdvsme3mO86CNRojKIzwRfXQ?size_mode=3&size=1024x768))

`setGlobalZOrder()`, does nothing:

```
red.setGlobalZOrder(2);
green.setGlobalZOrder(3);
blue.setGlobalZOrder(1);
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using cocos2d-js, but in cocos2d-x as far as I remember setGlobalZOrder doesn't do anything too. Instead I'm using setLocalZOrder.  Everything on default has z order 0.

Comment: It's weird. For now I solved it with sorting layers (just usual layers with localZOrder) and containers that manage behaviour of their 'fake' children, that in fact are children of one of sorting layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on github:

> The global z order is affecting only for `Sprite` objects.
>
> [Github issue link](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/14675#issuecomment-165754734)

So it didn't work for me, because I was playing with `LayerColor`.